# add script to work only when id (cedula) is selected

Tags: php

[view example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mCMRF.png)

I would like this script that validates the ID (CEDULA) at the time of choosing the ID option, it only works there while the passport is chosen, do not do anything that allows you to enter only the data since I cannot do it for 2 days I am just starting in this world fully appreciate your help.

```
<?php
if ($_GET['id']) {
    $cliente = $clienteNegocio->recuperar($_GET['id']);
    $txtAction = 'Editar';          
}else{
    $cliente = new cliente();
    $txtAction = 'Agregar';
}

?>
 <script>
function setMaxLength(){
    var inputVal = document.getElementById("tipoDoc")
    var selIndex = inputVal.options[inputVal.selectedIndex].value
    var inputNum = document.getElementById("nroDoc");



if( selIndex === "Cedula"){

        inputNum.maxLength = 10
        selIndex.substr(0, 9);
        inputNum.value = inputNum.value.substr(0, 9);

    } else{

        // Set your own limit here
        // if selIndex === "Pasaporte"
        inputNum.maxLength = 20
    }
}
</script>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="page-header">
        <h1><?php echo $txtAction; ?> Cliente</h1>
      </div>
        <form role="form" method="post" id="principal">
            <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $cliente->getId();?>" >
            
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="nombre">Nombre</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nombre" name="nombre" placeholder="Nombre" value="<?php echo $cliente->getNombre();?>" required>
                <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="apellido">Apellidos</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="apellido" name="apellido" placeholder="Apellido" value="<?php echo $cliente->getApellido();?>" required>
                <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="tipoDoc">Tipo de Documento</label>
                <select class="form-control" id="tipoDoc" name="tipoDoc" onChange="setMaxLength()">
                    <option value="Cedula"  <?php if($cliente->getTipoDoc() == 'Cedula') {echo "selected";} ?>  >Cedula</option>
                    <option value="Pasaporte" <?php if($cliente->getTipoDoc() == 'Pasaporte') {echo "selected";} ?> >Pasaporte</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
            <!-- Aquí el método onKeyPress se usa para verificar si la entrada es un número
                en <input type = "number" /> no se puede establecer maxLength
                por lo tanto, debe establecer <input type = "text" />-->
                <label for="nroDoc">Numero de Documento</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nroDoc" maxlength=10  onkeypress="if ( isNaN(this.value + String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode) )) return false;"
                 name="nroDoc" placeholder="Numero de Documento" value="<?php echo $cliente ->getNroDoc();?>" required>
                <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
            </div>
</form>
</div>
```

this is the script i want to add:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
         
         
//Validation of ID
          validarcedula = function () {
            numero = document.formacedula.cedula.value;
            /* alert(numero); */

            var suma = 0;
            var residuo = 0;
            var pri = false;
            var pub = false;
            var nat = false;
            var numeroProvincias = 22;
            var modulo = 11;

            //I verify that the field does not contain letters
            var ok = 1;
            for (i = 0; i < numero.length && ok == 1; i++) {
              var n = parseInt(numero.charAt(i));
              if (isNaN(n)) ok = 0;
            }
            if (ok == 0) {
              alert("No puede ingresar caracteres en el número");
              guardar.disabled=true;
              return false;
            }

            if (numero.length < 10) {
              alert('El número ingresado no es válido');
              guardar.disabled=true;
              return false;
            }

            //The first two digits correspond to the code of the province
            provincia = numero.substr(0, 2);
            if (provincia < 1 || provincia > numeroProvincias) {
              alert('El código de la provincia (dos primeros dígitos) es inválido');
              guardar.disabled=true;
              return false;
            }

            //Here we store the digits of the ID in variables.
            d1 = numero.substr(0, 1);
            d2 = numero.substr(1, 1);
            d3 = numero.substr(2, 1);
            d4 = numero.substr(3, 1);
            d5 = numero.substr(4, 1);
            d6 = numero.substr(5, 1);
            d7 = numero.substr(6, 1);
            d8 = numero.substr(7, 1);
            d9 = numero.substr(8, 1);
            d10 = numero.substr(9, 1);

            //The third digit is: 
            // 9 for private companies and foreigners
            //6 for public companies * /
            //less than 6 (0,1,2,3,4,5) for natural persons 

            if (d3 == 7 || d3 == 8) {
              alert('El tercer dígito ingresado es inválido');
              guardar.disabled=true;
              return false;
            }

            //Only for natural persons (module 10)
            if (d3 < 6) {
              nat = true;
              p1 = d1 * 2; if (p1 >= 10) p1 -= 9;
              p2 = d2 * 1; if (p2 >= 10) p2 -= 9;
              p3 = d3 * 2; if (p3 >= 10) p3 -= 9;
              p4 = d4 * 1; if (p4 >= 10) p4 -= 9;
              p5 = d5 * 2; if (p5 >= 10) p5 -= 9;
              p6 = d6 * 1; if (p6 >= 10) p6 -= 9;
              p7 = d7 * 2; if (p7 >= 10) p7 -= 9;
              p8 = d8 * 1; if (p8 >= 10) p8 -= 9;
              p9 = d9 * 2; if (p9 >= 10) p9 -= 9;
              modulo = 10;
            }

            suma = p1 + p2 + p3 + p4 + p5 + p6 + p7 + p8 + p9;
            residuo = suma % modulo;

            //If remainder = 0, dig.ver. = 0, otherwise 10 - remainder 
            digitoVerificador = residuo == 0 ? 0 : modulo - residuo;

            //now we compare the element of position 10 with the dig. see
            if (nat == true) {
              if (digitoVerificador != d10) {
                alert('El número de cédula es incorrecto.');
                guardar.disabled=true;
                return false;
              }
              if (digitoVerificador == d10)
              {
                alert('El número de cédula es correcto.');
                guardar.disabled=false;
                return true;
              }
            }
            return true;
          }
        </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

````
<?php
    if ($_GET['id']) {
        $cliente = $clienteNegocio->recuperar($_GET['id']);
        $txtAction = 'Editar';          
    }else{
        $cliente = new cliente();
        $txtAction = 'Agregar';
    }

    ?>
<script>
    
    /*Validacion de Cedula*/
    function validarcedula(val) {
        console.log(val)
        numero = val;
        /* alert(numero); */

        var suma = 0;
        var residuo = 0;
        var pri = false;
        var pub = false;
        var nat = false;
        var numeroProvincias = 22;
        var modulo = 11;

        /* Verifico que el campo no contenga letras */
        var ok = 1;
        for (i = 0; i < numero.length && ok == 1; i++) {
            var n = parseInt(numero.charAt(i));
            if (isNaN(n)) ok = 0;
        }
        if (ok == 0) {
            alert("No puede ingresar caracteres en el número");
            guardar.disabled=true;
            return false;
        }

        if (numero.length < 10) {
            alert('El número ingresado no es válido');
            guardar.disabled=true;
            return false;
        }

        /* Los primeros dos digitos corresponden al codigo de la provincia */
        provincia = numero.substr(0, 2);
        if (provincia < 1 || provincia > numeroProvincias) {
            alert('El código de la provincia (dos primeros dígitos) es inválido');
            guardar.disabled=true;
            return false;
        }

        /* Aqui almacenamos los digitos de la cedula en variables. */
        d1 = numero.substr(0, 1);
        d2 = numero.substr(1, 1);
        d3 = numero.substr(2, 1);
        d4 = numero.substr(3, 1);
        d5 = numero.substr(4, 1);
        d6 = numero.substr(5, 1);
        d7 = numero.substr(6, 1);
        d8 = numero.substr(7, 1);
        d9 = numero.substr(8, 1);
        d10 = numero.substr(9, 1);

        /* El tercer digito es: */
        /* 9 para sociedades privadas y extranjeros   */
        /* 6 para sociedades publicas */
        /* menor que 6 (0,1,2,3,4,5) para personas naturales */

        if (d3 == 7 || d3 == 8) {
            alert('El tercer dígito ingresado es inválido');
            guardar.disabled=true;
            return false;
        }

        /* Solo para personas naturales (modulo 10) */
        if (d3 < 6) {
            nat = true;
            p1 = d1 * 2; if (p1 >= 10) p1 -= 9;
            p2 = d2 * 1; if (p2 >= 10) p2 -= 9;
            p3 = d3 * 2; if (p3 >= 10) p3 -= 9;
            p4 = d4 * 1; if (p4 >= 10) p4 -= 9;
            p5 = d5 * 2; if (p5 >= 10) p5 -= 9;
            p6 = d6 * 1; if (p6 >= 10) p6 -= 9;
            p7 = d7 * 2; if (p7 >= 10) p7 -= 9;
            p8 = d8 * 1; if (p8 >= 10) p8 -= 9;
            p9 = d9 * 2; if (p9 >= 10) p9 -= 9;
            modulo = 10;
        }

        suma = p1 + p2 + p3 + p4 + p5 + p6 + p7 + p8 + p9;
        residuo = suma % modulo;

        /* Si residuo=0, dig.ver.=0, caso contrario 10 - residuo*/
        digitoVerificador = residuo == 0 ? 0 : modulo - residuo;

        /* ahora comparamos el elemento de la posicion 10 con el dig. ver.*/
        if (nat == true) {
            if (digitoVerificador != d10) {
                alert('El número de cédula es incorrecto.');
                guardar.disabled=true;
                return false;
            }
            if (digitoVerificador == d10)
            {
                alert('El número de cédula es correcto.');
                guardar.disabled=false;
                return true;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
    function setMaxLength(){
        var inputVal = document.getElementById("tipoDoc")
        var selIndex = inputVal.options[inputVal.selectedIndex].value
        var inputNum = document.getElementById("nroDoc");

        console.log(selIndex, inputNum, "Length")

        if( selIndex === "Cedula"){

            inputNum.maxLength = 10
            selIndex.substr(0, 9);
            inputNum.value = inputNum.value.substr(0, 9);  

        } else{

            // Set your own limit here
            // if selIndex === "Pasaporte"
            inputNum.maxLength = 200
        }
    }

    function checkKeyPress(existingValue, keycode){

        
        // Keypress check
        var inputVal = document.getElementById("tipoDoc")
        var selIndex = inputVal.options[inputVal.selectedIndex].value
        var status = false
        var stringVal = existingValue + String.fromCharCode(keycode)

        if( selIndex === "Cedula"){

            if(isNaN(stringVal)) {
                status =  false;
            }else {
                if(stringVal.length === 10){
                    validarcedula(stringVal)
                }
                status =  true;
            }
        } else{
            status =   true;
        }
        // console.log(existingValue, keycode, status, "Key press")
        return status;

        
    }
</script>
<div class="container">
      <div class="page-header">
        <h1>Cliente</h1>
      </div>
        <form role="form" method="post" id="principal">
            <input type="hidden" name="id" value="1" >
            
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="nombre">Nombre</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nombre" name="nombre" placeholder="Nombre" value="1" required>
                <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="apellido">Apellidos</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="apellido" name="apellido" placeholder="Apellido" value="1" required>
                <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="tipoDoc">Tipo de Documento</label>
                <select class="form-control" id="tipoDoc" name="tipoDoc" onChange="setMaxLength()">
                    <option value="Cedula"  selected  >Cedula</option>
                    <option value="Pasaporte"  >Pasaporte</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
             <!-- Aquí el método onKeyPress se usa para verificar si la entrada es un número
                en <input type = "number" /> no se puede establecer maxLength
                por lo tanto, debe establecer <input type = "text" />
            -->
                <label for="nroDoc">Numero de Documento</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nroDoc" maxlength=10  onkeypress="return checkKeyPress(this.value, event.keyCode)"
                 name="nroDoc" placeholder="Numero de Documento" value="1" required>
                <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="direccion">Direccion</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="direccion" name="direccion" placeholder="Direccion" value="1" required>
                <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="convencional">Convencional</label>
                <input type="number" class="form-control" id="convencional" name="convencional" placeholder="Convencional" value="1" required>
                <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="telefono">Telefono</label>
                <input type="number" class="form-control" id="telefono" name="telefono" placeholder="Telefono" value="1" required>
                <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="email">Email</label>
                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" value="1" required>
                <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
            </div>
            
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default cancelForm">Cancelar</button>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">1</button>
        
        </form>
    </div>
    ```
````